# What should the size of the MPMediaItemPropertyArtwork in MPNowPlayingInfoCenter be?

Tags: ios9, mpnowplayinginfocenter

I want to set the image in iOS lock screen but the documentation never mentions the size of the artwork.  What should it be set to?

Answer (score 2):

On the apple forums people recommend 600x600 images or higher,

I found any lower than that looks blurry.

https://discussions.apple.com/thread/6521841?start=0&tstart=0

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is for 21 day ago but i answer for someone who want.
Its not important but if your image is very small, You don't have high quality. You can use big image for more quality.